# My Hyperledger Fabirc won't build with Go due to package issues with Fabric 1.1 vs 1.0

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Right now, I'm following this tutorial https://github.com/chainHero/heroes-service

After I've setup my `.go` and `yaml` and `toml` scripts, I do 
`dep ensure` and then `go build`.

I get the error

```
# github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/vendor/github.com/zmap/zlint/lints
vendor/github.com/zmap/zlint/lints/result.go:75:9: undefined: strings.ReplaceAll
# github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util
vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util/csp.go:47:8: cannot convert nil to type csr.KeyRequest
vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util/csp.go:132:37: cannot use req.KeyRequest (type *csr.KeyRequest) as type csr.KeyRequest in argument to getBCCSPKeyOpts
```

I've heard that's due to versioning issues of `1.0` vs `1.1`, the latter which I have. I thought this would be solved since in the `Gopkg.toml`

```
# github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/vendor/github.com/zmap/zlint/lints
vendor/github.com/zmap/zlint/lints/result.go:75:9: undefined: strings.ReplaceAll
# github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util
vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util/csp.go:47:8: cannot convert nil to type csr.KeyRequest
vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util/csp.go:132:37: cannot use req.KeyRequest (type *csr.KeyRequest) as type csr.KeyRequest in argument to getBCCSPKeyOpts
```

Do I still need to import the `Go` packages?

UPDATE:

I installed `Go 1.13.1` and now when I `go build` I get

```
build github.com/chainHero/heroes-service: cannot load github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/msp: open /home/luke/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/msp: no such file or directory
```

I'm guessing this has to do with using Fabric 1.0 here...

Comment: use `go >= 1.12`

Comment: We also stopped supporting Fabric releases earlier than 1.4.x a while back.

Comment: @GariSingh okay, so I guess it won't build properly since the packages in 1.0.x will be obsolete

Comment: Are you trying to build fabric-sdk-go or fabric?

Comment: @GariSingh Fabric SDK I believe.. Again i'm following https://github.com/chainHero/heroes-service

Answer (score 1):

From your error, it seems that Fabric v1.1 uses `strings.ReplaceAll` from the go standard library, and your installed version of Go doesn't support it.

According to the documentation of [strings.ReplaceAll](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace), it was added in go version 1.12, so you should use a go version >= 1.12